# find Autocorrect files LibreOffice Linux

Tags: linux, libreoffice, autocorrect

Where can I find the file where the auto-correct saves the words to correct?

I happen to custom the auto-correct with a lot of words, and maybe it would save a lot of time to insert them directly in the file? 
In any case, I put a lot of effort and time customizing the auto-correct to save a lot of my time when writing, so **I would need to SAVE said file** in order to use it in all my computers, and to skip adding word by word every time I have to re-install. I can't find on Internet where that file is placed.

Last, but not least: Does anybody know if it would be possible to make auto-correct correct specific words in a specific font? I mean, some words in a font and some words in other font. Thank you.

Comment: No specific answer, but this may give you a hint about how autocorrect is stored. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/%5Bsolved%5D-export-autocorrect-entries-from-libreoffice-to-csv-867742/ tom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Paths) you should have a `/user/autocorr` directory in your libreoffice user-specific directory.  You can see it's location for sure by going to `Tools`->`Options`->`LibreOffice`->`Paths`

When I added an entry to my autocorrect rules I got a file in that directory `acor_en-US.dat`, presumably you'll have something similar